# Add menu item for Import/Export context menu in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-oxygen

I'm trying to add a submenu to **Import** and **Export** items in Project-Explorer's context menu. But, I can't find the menuid/locationURI of those items on the menu.

[image]

Can someone please help me to add items to these Import/Export menu items in Eclipse. I'm using Oxygen version. I tried the below segment, but it adds the item under the import/export items.

```
   <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        <menuContribution

        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=addition">
        <command
        commandId="myplugin.command.mycommand"
        icon="icons/etool16/mycommand.png"
        label="Run mycommand"
        mnemonic="M1+P"
        tooltip="Do something with this project">
        </command>
        </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't add your own actions because they're not menus. Instead, [Import](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_importWizards.html?cp=2_1_1_182) and [Export](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_exportWizards.html?cp=2_1_1_159) Wizards have their own extension points so that you can start them via the main Import/Export wizards.

I'm a bit confused how you have an Import menu in your context menu.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By default, Import and Export extension points have been added to the context menu. My issue is, how to add new menu items in the above context menu as sub-menu of it.